# Нужна помощь для написания правила для RewriteRule

Tags: mod_rewrite

Суть вопроса состоит в том, что у нас есть произвольная CMS, и понятное дело что шаблон к ней находится гдето там ... /template/mytemplate/. И гедето там есть папки с картинками и прочей ерундой. Думаю  не стоит объяснять что при верстке нам необходимо указывать все пути туда, кудато, и этот путь таскать за собой не слишком удобно. Пытаюсь написать простое правило.

Если идет обращение вида /img/{любой файл} чтобы его искало в /template/mytemplate/img/

Вроде простая задача, и почему-то постоянно натыкаюсь на ошибку сервера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например картинки у нас хранятся в http://siteName/public/img/... мы же хотим чтобы можно было обратится как http://siteName/img/. Пишется следующее правило:

```
RewriteEngine On #собственно включай mod_rewrite
RewriteRule ^img\/(.*)$ public/img/$1 [L]
```

Правило в шаблоне примерно следующее - если запрос начинается с `/img/ЧТО_УГОДНО` то отдаем мы `/public/img/ЧТО_УГОДНО`
Надеюсь помог :)

Comment: Это называется меня заело :). Я забыл про экранирование слеша. Спасибо огромное.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)